# Can I connect a buzzer to gpio without a transistor?

Tags: gpio

I have a buzzer with an internal resistance of 16.5 Ohms, which I have used with an Arduino and it worked fine, so I assume it is 5V.

Can I connect a buzzer to the GPIO pins without a transistor, or would it damage the pins?

Comment: How could I know? I remember using that buzzer with an arduino and it worked fine, so I assume it is 5v.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum safe current from a GPIO pin is only [16mA](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#General_Purpose_Input.2FOutput_.28GPIO.29)

3.3v/16.5Ω would be ~200mA, so No. Definitely not safe

You would need to add a series resistor of 190Ω or more to make it safe to connect and then the voltage across the buzzer will be only 0.26V, so very very quiet

Comment: V=IR and all that...

Comment: Could @Euphorbium add a series resisitor? I don't know how buzzers work...

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, the buzzer would be very very quiet by the time the resistor was big enough